# MySQL Parameter in Case always NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a simplified example where I'm trying to generate a random number for each row in a dataset and have a case statement that maps the random value between 0 and 1 to an alphanumeric character.  The reason I'm approaching random characters in this fashion is so that I can set the percentage chance for each status character.

```
SELECT
@row := RAND() as random,
case @row
    when (SELECT @row) > .5 then 'A'
    when (SELECT @row) > .3 then 'D'
    when (SELECT @row) > .1 then 'C'
    when (SELECT @row) <= .1 then 'Z'
    else 'arg'
end as status 
FROM 
(SELECT @row := RAND()) r
```

however, this always returns 'arg' for my row and I would never expect to see this value.

Comment: Even though I have an answer to the problem I was trying to solve, I'm very curious why the original query behaves as it does.  Would definitely appreciate a quick walk through of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE  case_expression
   WHEN when_expression_1 THEN commands
   WHEN when_expression_2 THEN commands
   ...
   ELSE commands
END CASE;
```

The simple CASE statement to check the value of an expression against a set of unique values.

In order to perform more complex matches such as ranges, you use the searched CASE statement. The searched CASE statement is equivalent to the IF  statement, however, its construct is much more readable.

```
CASE 
   WHEN when_expression_1 THEN commands
   WHEN when_expression_2 THEN commands
   ...
   ELSE commands
END CASE;
```

Since you are using range expression in comparison you have to remove `@row` after `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why the query in the question is always returning 'arg', I have a much simpler way to generate the random characters that I was trying to achieve:

```
SELECT substring('AAAAACD', ROUND((RAND() * (7-1))+1), 1);
```

This will substring one character from 'AAAAACD' and by placing more or less characters in the original string I can control the prevalence of each character.